# Trying to install pandoc via cabal install fails

Tags: installation, package-management, haskell, pandoc

Since the [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html) package in the repository is outdated, I would like to install it via `cabal-install`.

I ran `cabal update`, and then `cabal install pandoc` which fails with:

`cabal: Couldn't read cabal file "pandoc/1.9.4.4/pandoc.cabal"`

This might be relevant:

```
cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.10.2
using version 1.10.1.0 of the Cabal library
```

my machine is running oneiric.

Answer (score 3):

Type `echo $PATH` and you'll probably see something that either (a) does not include $HOME/.cabal/bin or contains `$HOME/.cabal/bin` near the end.

Type `export PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH`, and then `cabal install cabal-install`. This will install the proper version of cabal, since the version in the ubuntu repositories is out-of-date. Then, you can `cabal install pandoc` just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
After replicated your recommended steps I now get the following error when running `cabal install cabal-install`:

```Building cabal-install-1.16.0.1...

Main.hs:75:8:
    Could not find module `Distribution.Verbosity':
      There are files missing in the `Cabal-1.16.0.1' package,
      try running 'ghc-pkg check'.
      Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.```

Comment: When running `ghc-pkg check` I get a long list of broken packages.