# Install Pandoc (required for docverter)

Tags: software-installation, pandoc

For the life of me I can't figure out how to install pandoc. I tried [the approach recommended on its Github repo](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Installing-the-development-version-of-pandoc) as well as all [3 approaches recommended on the pandoc site](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html). I'm installing on Ubuntu 12.04 so I first did `sudo apt-get install haskell-platform`.

Here's where the error occurred at each step:

**1) Installing as recommended on the Github repo:**

```
# cabal install --enable-tests
Registering zlib-conduit-1.0.0...
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
http-conduit-1.9.4.5 depends on mime-types-0.1.0.3 which failed to install.
mime-types-0.1.0.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 9
pandoc-1.12 depends on mime-types-0.1.0.3 which failed to install.
```

**2) Primary installation method on Pandoc site:**

```
# cabal install pandoc
[35 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Parsing ( src/Text/Pandoc/Parsing.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Parsing.o )
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
pandoc-1.11.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 9
```

**3)  "If my distribution has GHC 6.12"**

```
# cabal install cabal-install
[46 of 67] Compiling Distribution.Simple.LocalBuildInfo ( Distribution/Simple/LocalBuildInfo.hs, dist/build/Distribution/Simple/LocalBuildInfo.o )
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Cabal-1.16.0.3 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 9
cabal-install-1.16.0.2 depends on Cabal-1.16.0.3 which failed to install.
```

**4) Installing the tarball:**

```
# cabal install pandoc
[23 of 45] Compiling Text.Pandoc.Writers.Texinfo ( src/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Texinfo.hs, dist/build/Text/Pandoc/Writers/Texinfo.o )
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
pandoc-1.11.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 9
```

Comment: why not install directly from the repos? `sudo apt-get install pandoc`

Comment: great,thanks that worked! feel free to convert to an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can install directly from the repos:

```
sudo apt-get install pandoc
```

Comment: I get `pandoc 1.9.1.1` by this way. Isn't there a newest version available ?

Comment: totally no...I get `E: Unable to locate package pandoc`

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? It’s available at least in trusty and xenial onwards.

Comment: Solution is outdated. Current version of pandoc on apt is 2.9. Recent version is 2.17. Significant changes with these two versions. I didn't want to manually install the deb package and used the package manager homebrew instead. https://brew.sh/

Comment: the solution is not outdated - it works. the `pandoc` version you are getting may not be the latest, as is typical with many distros, especially with LTS versions.

Answer (score 21):

I found that installing `cabal` took up a lot of disk space in my VM, so I prefer to use the `deb` that the pandoc developers provide. Here's what I do to download and install the current deb (for pandoc v15.1.1):

```
sudo wget https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/download/1.15.1/pandoc-1.15.1-1-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i pandoc-1.15.1-1-amd64.deb
```

You can check the latest release numbers here: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/

---

Comment: This is was by far the easier solution to getting the newest version of Pandoc installed on my DigitalOcean vps. The apt-get version was 1.12 (I believe) and downloading the latest package with this method installed v1.17, which includes the wonderful feature of converting from docx, which i what I was after. Thanks @Ben!

Comment: This was by far the easiest way for me, too, for 1.19.1 (from 1.17.1). I love pandoc but I do find it terribly hard to install, and this worked like a charm.

Comment: Yep, apt-get for Ubuntu 14 in 2017 was useless so this was a lifesaver (no exaggeration given how awesome pandoc is).

Comment: I downloaded the [latest `*.deb` release](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/) (in my case, 2.1.1) from Github and installed it in 18.04 (pre-release) with the GDebi Package Manager. Worked a treat. Makes life *much* easier!!

Comment: In case anyone else was thrown off here -- I am on `x86_64` and didn't bother checking if the `amd64` binary would work for my architecture -- especially since the [releases](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases) page goes to pains to list `x86_64` separately for some other OSes. But they are indeed compatible (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/q/601553/362864)! I just installed from the amd64.deb and no issues.

Answer (score 12):

As pointed out by Stephane Laurent, the version of pandoc in the repos is far from the newest and doesn't allow nice features such as handling citations with `--biblio`. I struggled to install the newest version using the instructions on the [pandoc website](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html) and [github](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/blob/master/INSTALL) but here's how I finally did it for Ubuntu 13.10.

1. Install `cabal`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install cabal-install
   ```
2. Update `cabal` package database

   ```
   cabal update
   ```
3. Make sure that path to `cabal` is at *start* of PATH (tip from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204122/trying-to-install-pandoc-via-cabal-install-fails))

   ```
   PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH
   ```
4. Use `cabal` to install `alex` and `happy`

   ```
   cabal install alex happy
   ```
5. Use `cabal` to install `pandoc` (and `pandoc-citeproc` if wanted)

   ```
   cabal install pandoc pandoc-citeproc
   ```
6. Check pandoc version to confirm installed

   ```
   pandoc --version
   ```

You'll need to add the `PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH` command to your [~/.profile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) so it's available on your next restart. Happy converting!

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues trying to install pandoc on a 512 MB machine in the clouds. According to a comment for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104630/exitfailure-9-when-trying-to-install-ghc-mod-using-cabal) I was getting the `ExitFailure 9` because GHC was receiving a SIGKILL because I was using too much memory. To me this explained the lack of any useful messages with verbose switched on. I turned off ghc optimizations by installing with `cabal-dev install pandoc --ghc-options="-O0"` and pandoc compiled fine with a far smaller memory footprint. This is not a smart idea if you are in a production environment though!

Comment: do you get a version more recent than 1.9.1.1 by this way ?

Answer (score 0):

Because Pandoc has some dependencies, users need to install both pandoc and the dependencies to enable a success of pandoc usage for Ubuntu 20.04 (or 18.04).

**1.Check dependencies**

If you have a tensorflow env within Miniconda or Anaconda, please check the dependencies.

```
$ conda list
```

*It will show nbclient, nbconvert, etc.*

**2.Install the lastest pandoc**

*Usage guide:*

*https://pandoc.org/installing.html*

*Download pandoc*

*https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/3.1.8*

*Installation*

```
$ cd Downloads
$ sudo dpkg -i pandoc-3.1.8-1-amd64.deb
```

**3.Install texlive-xetex**

```
$ sudo apt-get update -y
$ sudo apt-get install -y texlive-xetex
```

After successful installation, users can download pdf from Jupyter Noterbook (ipynb document)